# flex to red5 v0.9: Client rejected, unscheduling waitForHandshakeJob

Tags: apache-flex, red5, flash-builder, rtmp

I'm trying to connect from adobe flash builder 4 beta to red5 v0.9 rc2 (latest svn).

i try to connect using the exact following example:
http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/615/3/Getting-started-with-red5-server/Page3.html

i get the following error message:

```
INFO] [NioProcessor-3] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Connecting to: [WebScope@627b5c Depth = 1, Path = '/default', Name = 'mytestapp']
[WARN] [NioProcessor-3] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Client rejected, unscheduling waitForHandshakeJob
org.red5.server.exception.ClientRejectedException: Client rejected
```

i can't seem to figure out what's the problem. can anyone please provide any information regarding to what may have caused this ?

i tried both on rtmp and rtmpe protocol but i receive the same error message.

thanks

#### update

I tried also using flex builder 3 and i get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Client rejected, unscheduling waitForHandshakeJob`

this just means that the server rejected the connection. 
the server side scripting rejected the connection because i did not provide several required parameters by the application.